# Why Does Iron-Router onBeforeAction Logic Not Affect the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I've decided to implement a quick little animation between pages for Meteor. The way I've decided to do this is by using a onBeforeAction hook, to set a DOM element to `display:none`, and then to animate it in with an onAfterAction.

The problem is, the element never disappears off the screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my route:

```
Router.route('/priority/:_id', {
  path: '/priority/:_id',
  template: 'priority',
  data: function(){
    return Priorities.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    $('.show-title').css('display', 'none'); 
    this.next();
  }
  // ,
  // onAfterAction: function() {
  //   $('.show-title').velocity('transition.fadeIn', 1000);
  // }
})
```

And for reference, here's the template:

```
<template name="priority">
  <h1 class="show-title">Priority: {{title}}</h1>
</template>
```

Am I not understanding how to use these actions properly?

Comment: Move that to your `Template.priority.rendered`. onBeforeAction is before the DOM is loaded and even onAfterAction can be before, depending on how you use your templates. Normally, onBeforeAction will be used to prep data to be passed to helpers (I put my subscriptions there). I wouldn't put DOM manipulations into the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks are called immediately, before the DOMs ready.

You need to do that in the template's rendered function instead:

```
Template.priority.rendered = function() {
    $('.show-title').css('display', 'none');
    $('.show-title').velocity('transition.fadeIn', 1000);
}
```

Comment: If I use this technique, how can I cause my previous page to also have an animation? If I use Template.priorities.destroyed (my previous view), it won't run animations because these are callbacks after the view is removed.